# PyQt5 <=> Pycharm on WIN 10

Tags: pycharm, pyqt5

I know it has been asked many times but I ( also ) get the error :

> Connection   :  False Drivers      :  ['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3',
> 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7'] Last error   :  Driver not loaded Driver not loaded

with `PostgreSQL 14` and `Python 3.10.2`.

I have placed the following files mostly everywhere I though it could help but without any result.

Database connection with `Pycharm` internal database access is ok ( it means id, pwd, etc ... are ok ). Indeed, I can see data from the various table. I also have installed PyQt5 with pip, including PyQt5-tools.

`libiconv-2.dll, libintl-9.dll, libpd.dll, libpq.lib, qsqlpsql.dll`

What can I do ?

Cordially,

Luc

---

Test lines used :

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView

db = QSqlDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName('127.0.0.1')
db.setDatabaseName('test')
db.setUserName('luc')
db.setPassword('xxxxxxxx')

if not db.open():
    print("\n=> Unable to connect to the database")
    print('\nConnection   : ', db.isOpen())
    print('Drivers      : ', db.drivers())
    print('Last error   : ', db.lastError().text())
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print("\n=> Connect to the database successful")
```

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says: QSqlDatabase: an instance of QCoreApplication is required for loading driver plugins

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    db = QSqlDatabase("QPSQL")
    db.setHostName('127.0.0.1')
    db.setDatabaseName('test')
    db.setUserName('luc')
    db.setPassword('xxxxxxxx')

    if not db.open():
        print("\n=> Unable to connect to the database")
        print('\nConnection   : ', db.isOpen())
        print('Drivers      : ', db.drivers())
        print('Last error   : ', db.lastError().text())
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("\n=> Connect to the database successful")

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I have made your proposed change but unfortunately the output remain the same.  What can I try else ?

Comment: @Luc as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#details), you should use [`addDatabase()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase): `db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QPSQL')`.

Comment: I have installed PostgreSQL on a new Win 10 PC, Pycharm and Python 10. Same results with same program but without insert same dll everywhere. It seems there is something I must do on Win 10 as I have another PC running Kubunto and everything is working 100 %.

I do not know what to try on Win 10 !

Comment: Thanks for your reply musicamante. Test already done as you suggested with and without the add of if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv).  But no change either !

Comment: I have added : print('\nIs QPSQL driver available : ',db.isDriverAvailable('QPSQL')) to be sure the driver is available and result is ok, but no suggestion above solve the situation.  I have : C:\Users\LHA>pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
guidata       2.0.4
guiqwt        4.0.2
numpy         1.22.3
packaging     21.3
Pillow        9.0.1
pip           22.0.4
pyparsing     3.0.7
pyqt-tools    1.0.0
PyQt5         5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip     12.9.1
PyQt5Designer 5.14.1
PythonQwt     0.10.1
QtPy          2.0.1
scipy         1.8.0

Comment: Strange enough PyQt5 installed at : C:\Users\LHA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin. This seams a very long path to PyQt5 ( installed with pip install pyqt5 and all paths added to system variables path).

Comment: Is QPSQL driver available :  True

=> Unable to connect to the database

Connection   :  False
Drivers      :  ['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
Last error   :  Driver not loaded Driver not loaded ...... So I am totally lost !

Comment: You can try to open QSQLPSQL.DLL in dependency walker to check if all dependencies is found, it's probably build with msvc compiler and depends on visual c redistributible (vcruntime140.dll) which may be missing

Comment: I have checked if vcruntime140.dll was present and it is indeed well available. No change on the status unfortunately.

Comment: Problem solved. I have used ODBC driver and it works now perfectly. I am convinced there is an external driver missing for postgresql. Problem was identical on 3 PC Win 10.